# How do I use a TimeSeriesSplit with a GridSearchCV object to tune a model in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I've searched the [sklearn docs for  `TimeSeriesSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) and the [docs for cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#time-series-split) but I haven't been able to find a working example.

I'm using sklearn version 0.19.

This is my setup

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2], [3.1, 3.5, 1.0, 2.1, 8.3, 1.1]]).T
y = np.array([1, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3])
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2)
for train, test in tscv.split(X):
    print(train, test)
```

gives:

```
[0 1] [2 3]
[0 1 2 3] [4 5]
```

If I try:

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
param_search = {'max_depth' : [3, 5]}

my_cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2).split(X)
gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, cv=my_cv,
                        param_grid=param_search)
gsearch.fit(X, y)
```

it gives: `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`

I get the problem: `GridSearchCV` is trying to call `len(cv)` but `my_cv` is an iterator without length. However, the [docs for `GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) state I can use a

> int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional

I tried using `TimeSeriesSplit` without the `.split(X)` but it still didn't work.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, thanks!!

Comment: Try using `my_cv = [(train,test) for train, test in TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2).split(X)]`

Comment: that works, thanks! But shouldn't the function work with an iterator? When the number of observations is large (worse if the number of folds is large) I'd rather not hold those big arrays in memory if possible

Comment: Yes it should. You should post an issue on the scikit-learn github page.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It turns out the problem was I was using `GridSearchCV` from `sklearn.grid_search`, which is deprecated. Importing `GridSearchCV` from `sklearn.model_selection` resolved the problem:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2], [3.1, 3.5, 1.0, 2.1, 8.3, 1.1]]).T
y = np.array([1, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3])

model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
param_search = {'max_depth' : [3, 5]}

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2)
gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, cv=tscv,
                        param_grid=param_search)
gsearch.fit(X, y)
```

gives:

```
GridSearchCV(cv=<generator object TimeSeriesSplit.split at 0x11ab4abf8>,
       error_score='raise',
       estimator=XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0,
       learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3,
       min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100, nthread=-1,
       objective='reg:linear', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
       scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=True, subsample=1),
       fit_params=None, iid=True, n_jobs=1,
       param_grid={'max_depth': [3, 5]}, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs',
       refit=True, return_train_score=True, scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but it seems to me that as of the current implementation the line my_cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2).split(X) should actually be corrected to my_cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2). Otherwise it will throw an error